# How to get month in previous year?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get the **previous month** according to current month. But the problem occurs when "year" is not 2017.

[image]

So how can I get the month of the previous year?. The code below will describe what I want, if anybody know how to get it please tell me the method. Thank you :)

```js
var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var cur_month = new Date();
  var cur_month_now = month[cur_month.getMonth()];
  var pre_month_1 = month[cur_month.getMonth()-1];
  var pre_month_2 = month[cur_month.getMonth()-2];
  var pre_month_3 = month[cur_month.getMonth()-3];
  var pre_month_4 = month[cur_month.getMonth()-4];
  var pre_month_5 = month[cur_month.getMonth()-5];

  document.getElementById("cur_month").innerHTML = cur_month_now;
  document.getElementById("pre_month_1").innerHTML = pre_month_1;
  document.getElementById("pre_month_2").innerHTML = pre_month_2;
  document.getElementById("pre_month_3").innerHTML = pre_month_3;
  document.getElementById("pre_month_4").innerHTML = pre_month_4;
  document.getElementById("pre_month_5").innerHTML = pre_month_5;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Month
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#" id="cur_month"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_1"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_2"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_3"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_4"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_5"></a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this undefined because `month[-1]` and `month[-2]` are `undefined`

You need to actually do date manipulation in a date object rather than just getting date from index.

Use this method to get last month date

```
function getPrevMonth(date) {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  return date;
}
```

invoke this method as many times as you need.

**Demo**

```js
function getPrevMonth(date) {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  return date;
}

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var cur_month = new Date();
var cur_month_now = month[cur_month.getMonth()];
var pre_month_1 = month[getPrevMonth(cur_month).getMonth()];
var pre_month_2 = month[getPrevMonth(cur_month).getMonth()];
var pre_month_3 = month[getPrevMonth(cur_month).getMonth()];
var pre_month_4 = month[getPrevMonth(cur_month).getMonth()];
var pre_month_5 = month[getPrevMonth(cur_month).getMonth()];

document.getElementById("cur_month").innerHTML = cur_month_now;
document.getElementById("pre_month_1").innerHTML = pre_month_1;
document.getElementById("pre_month_2").innerHTML = pre_month_2;
document.getElementById("pre_month_3").innerHTML = pre_month_3;
document.getElementById("pre_month_4").innerHTML = pre_month_4;
document.getElementById("pre_month_5").innerHTML = pre_month_5;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Month
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="cur_month"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `Date` do the wrap-around for you. There are also a couple of improvements we can make to the code, see comments:

```js
// Array initializers are cleaner and less typing
var month = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
];

var dt = new Date();
var cur_month_now = month[dt.getMonth()];
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1); // Date handles wrapping to previous year
var pre_month_1 = month[dt.getMonth()];
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_2 = month[dt.getMonth()];
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_3 = month[dt.getMonth()];
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_4 = month[dt.getMonth()];
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() - 1);
var pre_month_5 = month[dt.getMonth()];

document.getElementById("cur_month").innerHTML = cur_month_now;
document.getElementById("pre_month_1").innerHTML = pre_month_1;
document.getElementById("pre_month_2").innerHTML = pre_month_2;
document.getElementById("pre_month_3").innerHTML = pre_month_3;
document.getElementById("pre_month_4").innerHTML = pre_month_4;
document.getElementById("pre_month_5").innerHTML = pre_month_5;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Month
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="cur_month"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a bit more concise, and using modulo operator:

```js
var month = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"
           .split(','),
    monthNum = 12 + new Date().getMonth();
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a'), function (elem, i) {
    elem.textContent = month[(monthNum-i)%12];
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Month
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="cur_month"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_1"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_4"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="pre_month_5"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

NB: It is better practice to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, since you want to put text, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really new, but for smaller js code …

```js
function getPrevMonth(date, m) {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - m);
  return date;
}

//no need for such array
locale = "en-us";//or e.g. navigator.languages[0]
var d = new Date();

for (var i=0; i<6; i++){
  //also worth trying: create element instead of writing to exiting ones only: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp
  document.getElementById("pre_month_"+i).innerHTML =  getPrevMonth(d,1).toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Month
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_0"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="pre_month_5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```